# Bulk API client for .NET

Tags: bulk-api, .net

I am looking for SalesForce Bulk API client to perform big data load/upload. Currently I am calling api manually building/parsing csv files, building request xml. Looking for more convenient way to use Bulk API.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to manually perform the Bulk API calls from code you can use the [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader).

This includes a command line interface that you could use to automate the process as required.